# Parsing XML code from Yahoo Weather

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to parse XML data from the following link:

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12776781&u=f

I would like to grab the text, code and temp from the following line:

`<yweather:condition  text="Light Rain"  code="11"  temp="78"  date="Fri, 26 Jul 2013 1:55 pm EDT" />`

I'm currently using this code, but can't figure out how to modify this to retrieve the above values.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You have to parse the XML and populate whatever data structures you need to provide data to your table view. Start with NSXMLParser to parse the XML.

Comment: I'm only showing partial code. If I grab <title> from the XML, as shown above, it works. But I can't figure out how to change @"title" to get the weather condition text, code and temp.

Comment: Have you already parsed those values? Do you have access to the additional values from your `feeds` variable? If so, then use `stringWithFormat:` to build the complete string you want to display.

Comment: That link doesn't work for me, but after you parse the xml, it should be sitting in a dictionary/array type of structure, probably the one you call "feeds" in your code above.  In that case, do a "po feeds" in the debugger, and see what structure(s) are generated by the parser, and change your code accordingly.

Comment: As a newbie, I understand what you're telling me to do, but I'm not sure how to implement the print out. Do you have a link or hint? Thanks in advance.

I also see I should've posted my full code, it was just a sample from another tutorial however.